# Attributes and custom attributes - how does authorize work?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to emulate the `[Authorize]` attribute because I find it amazing that you can just stick an attribute on top of an entire class and it somehow does all this wizardy to prevent people running the methods in the class unless... something...

I looked up creating custom attributes and found a few answers that basically say it's not possible for an attribute to prevent a method being called unless we use reflection, so then I decided to dig into the Authorize attribute but can only find the "interface" methods on a metadata file so basically

What exactly is the `[Authorize]` attribute doing and how can I implement attributes to actually do things using reflection? E.g. the following does nothing when attributed to a class:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class Authorise : System.Attribute
{
    public Authorise()
    {
        if (!SomeBoolCondition) throw new Exception ("Oh no!");
    }
}
```

I can't get my head round how the Authorize attribute does checks and then redirects the program to a sign in page.

Comment: there are internal classes that do the routing, and before they route to your action, they check if it has an AuthorizeAttribute and check the permissions. They call the methods `OnAuthorization, AuthorizeCore, HandleUnauthorizedRequest` of AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: asp.net core is completely open source.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or Asp.Net Core..but basically it checks if logged in Identity is Authenticated. Depends on the configuration it could be Windows Indentity, ClaimsIdentity etc. You can create your own if you want to Authorized authenticated user based on roles, claims etc. Note `Authentication` and `Authorization` are two different things

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an open ended question about how the framework works, which is more suitable for looking up tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement your own authorization logic with a custom attribute, you'll need create and register [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the request pipeline as well. Your middleware will receive the entire HttpContext, and you can use that to check your endpoint for the CustomAuthorizeAttribute via it's meta data. From there you can implement the authorization logic and decide to continue processing the request in the pipeline with "await next.Invoke()", or stop processing and return an unauthorized response to the client.

Attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IEnumerable<string> AllowedUserRoles { get; private set; }

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] allowedUserRoles)
    {
        this.AllowedUserRoles = allowedUserRoles.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Controller with custom attribute:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[CustomAuthorize("Admin", "Supervisor", "Worker")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Startup.Configure with custom middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
    {
        var endpointMetaData = httpContext.GetEndpoint()
            .Metadata;

        bool hasCustomAuthorizeAttribute = endpointMetaData.Any(x => x is CustomAuthorizeAttribute);

        if (hasCustomAuthorizeAttribute)
        {
            // get the endpoint's instance of CustomAuthorizeAttribute
            CustomAuthorizeAttribute customAuthorieAttribute = endpointMetaData
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x is CustomAuthorizeAttribute) as CustomAuthorizeAttribute;

            // here you will have access to customAuthorizeAttribute.AllowedUserRoles
            // and can execute your custom logic with it
            bool isAuthorized = true;

            if (isAuthorized)
            {
                // continue processing the request
                await next.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                // stop processing request and return unauthorized response
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
            }
        }
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```